# Read / Write XmlDocument with Namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-namespaces

Consider the following `XmlDocument` with namespaces:

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DummyDataSource">
      <rd:DataSourceID>a0a7ff0a-a268-4f7e-b949-9427e308468a</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString />
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
</Report>
```

I wrote,

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.Load("c:\MyXml.xml")
Dim nsm As New XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
nsm.AddNamespace("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition")
nsm.AddNamespace("rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")
Dim xnd As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//DataSources/DataSource/...", nsm)
MessageBox.Show(xnd.Name)
```

I want to read and modify values of following tags (XPath):

1. `//DataSources/DataSource/rd:DataSourceID`
2. `//DataSources/DataSource/ConnectionProperties/DataProvider`

Comment: And what is the issue you are having? What errors? What exceptions?

Comment: And what isn't working right now with the code you do have?

Comment: Nothing is working My failed try quoted only for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to use LINQ to XML and then read the element using a proper XName instead of a string. Something like:

```
Dim defaultSpace As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition")    
Dim firstSource As XElement = doc.Element(defaultSpace + "DataSources").Element(defaultSpace + "DataSource")
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use these XPath formats and include the namespace-uri() - which is a pain in the neck:

```
//DataSources[namespace-uri()='']/DataSource[namespace-uri()='']/...
```

Comment: -1 I don't think namespace-uri is necessary. Define a prefix for the default namespace and use it instead.

Comment: You give downvote just because you think? You mean you even did not try?!

Comment: I have not given any downvote to you. I am opening this answer now only. Pl do not angry with me ya.. Tell me please what shall I do now?

Comment: It was John Saunders giving me downvote so not really angry with you - or even John Saunders. It is people's right to exercise but when someone does it and does not even bother to test the answer, that is just not acceptable. And for you, just try my XPath and see if it is working. If not let me know and I will update my answer or delete it.

Comment: Tried and failed. wd u pl tell me in detail, how to?